# How to display tiff image in a web browser

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

I am using MVC at the moment to return a tif file to the user.

```
 public ActionResult GetImage(string imageLocation)
        {
            return base.File(imageLocation, "image/tiff");
        }
```

However, I am using chrome at the moment and the file just downloads, I was wondering is there any way to show the image on the browser it self? can I stream it as a different image type?

any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

TIFF in browsers is an unsure thing - even more so with CMYK ones. I suggest conveting to JPG or PNG.

Although, if you really wanna do, safari only supports TIFF !

Also, [This](http://www.alternatiff.com/howtoembed.html) may be helpful.

Comment: The Image class in the framework can read TIFF images and write them out as a different file format. You could convert them to PNG for example.

Comment: Sounds reasonable, converting them on-the-fly/cached if there are lots of them. Maybe right up front/on-deploy if there aren't that many.

Comment: using the image class, can I return it as a stream rather than saving it to file?